# Check if string exist in a set of array values PHP

Tags: php

This has been pulled from the results of an sqli query

```
$colourCheckedArr = $colour_handler->pullCheckedcolour($colour_id); 
foreach ($colourCheckedArr as $colourCheckedArrs) {      
    $list_ = $colourCheckedArrs;                                
    $array = json_encode($list_);                                 
    echo $array . "\n";                             
}
```

I am new to this and its most likely the wrong syntax so how do I put it in the correct array syntax

> Output
>
> {"colours":"red"} {"colours":"blue"} {"colours":"green"};

From Barmar's answer

```
$needle = "red";
    if (in_array($needle, array_column($array, "colours"))) {
                            echo "Match found";
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            echo "No match found";
                            return false;
                        }
```

I seem to always get

> "No Match found"
> Please help

Comment: That's not PHP syntax for an array. You mean `[["colours" => "red"], ["colours" => "blue"], ["colours" => "green"]]`

Comment: Are you trying to check if a value exists in array or if one of the elements in the array contains substring? Please show expected output and correct input.

Comment: The question has been edited. I think I need to put the query results in an array and not a JSON list of objects but my question is how do I do so? & I am checking if there's a match within the array values ...expected output is Match found

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_column()` to get an array of all the `colours` values, then search that.

```
$array = [["colours" => "red"], ["colours" => "blue"], ["colours" => "green"]];
$needle = "red";
if (in_array($needle, array_column($array, "colours"))) {
    echo "Match found";
    return true;
} else {
    echo "No match found";
    return false;
}
```